# jQuery: moving to next input on Android/mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I have a set of input field (registration form).

On **desktop** the user either clicks a button to go to next input, or presses enter key. On both events a custom function will run:

```
$("#login").bind("keydown", function(event) {
    if (event.which === 13) { // enter pressed
        myFunction();
    }
}
```

This works well on desktop - user moves to next input and myFunction runs. On **mobile (tested on Anroid/Chrome)** the following happens when the user clicks the next-arrow in the bottom right corner of the keyboard:

- User moves to next input, but *myFunction* is not executed.

This is a problem as I need to run this function for the next input-field to be displayed. How can I detect this keypress in similar way as on desktop?

Comment: This is because you are using "keydown" event, try using "change" and check whether it is working. If working we can code based on it.

Comment: When using "change" it submits the form on desktop when pressing enter. No difference on mobile from when using keydown.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, @Alexis Toby. The bind-function was binded to the div itself so thats why change did not work.

`$(".login-input input").on("change",function() {` 
works as intended!